# Why is this jQueryUI dialog not working in IE9?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

The following code produces the expected jQueryUI modal popup dialog in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. However, it fails in Internet Explorer 9:

```
<html><head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#AddUser" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 'auto', width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Add": function() {
                alert("Add one!");
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    $( "#AddUserButton" ).button().click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $( "#AddUser" ).dialog( "open" );
    });


});
</script>

</head><body>

<div id="AddUser" title="Add User">Popup content here</div>
<input type="submit" id="AddUserButton" />

</body></html>
```

In IE 9 the #AddUser div is not a jQueryUI dialog. Is there anything that I am missing?

**EDIT**: Code updated to closer to production code.

Thanks.

Comment: @NadirMuzaffar: The div is simple displayed on the screen.

Comment: Are you using the lasted jquery/jqueryui version?

Comment: As mentioned in the code, the jQuery version is 1.7.1. However, the answer has already been found, see below. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you problem is the trailing "," IE doesn't like it

```
 $( "#AddUser" ).dialog({
                   autoOpen: false, modal: true >>,<<
            });
```

this will work:

```
 $( "#AddUser" ).dialog({
                   autoOpen: false, modal: true
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, that does fix it in the code that I had posted! However the production code has some other features, and there is no trailing comma on them. I updated the code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: This turned out to be a whole world of pain! You got me past the first hurdle, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try to add DOCTYPE in the html file. `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

Comment: Thanks, that in fact was _one_ of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is just a guess, but type="submit" sometimes is weird on ie...

have you tried:
`<button id="AddUserButton">AddUser</button>`

also i would call "preventDefault" as last action inside the action listener.

Comment: Thank you. However, the issue has already been solved, and IE happened to be fine with the <button> code. The issues seemed to be the extra comma `,` and the fact that I was using jQuery 1.5. Updating the jQuery 1.7 and removing the comma `,` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with dialog and adding following in css file did the job for me.

```
.ui-widget-overlay
{
        z-index: 0 !important;   
}
```